# Meaning of "You're on" in this situation

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the movie, Inception, 2010 film.
EAMES was sitting down, and COBB approached to him. And said,

> "**You're on.** You've got an hour. Now get us something useful."

I googled it and found this :

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36434/why-does-youre-on-mean-i-agree

But, seems it doesn't make sense for this. Right?

I just try to guess and maybe it means "It's your turn." doesn't it?

Could you please give a few examples in order for me to understand quick?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 11):

In this case, since EAMES already works for COBB, I think the meaning is more along the lines of definition 5 or 5.1 at [oxford dictionary.com's ON definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on?q=on#on) (thanks to MaulikV for the link):

> (Of an actor) on stage; performing.
>       *That's your cue. You're on.*
>
> (Of an employee) working; on duty.

I would lean more toward the "actor giving a performance" definition, as COBB's task is to trick someone into giving away information, but I think both senses are appropriate.

Comment: I still think it's about the **challenge** because of the reaction of EAMES. EAMES thought that the time allotted was supposed to be the **whole night**. Anyway, thanks for mentioning me in the most upvoted answer ;)

Comment: @MaulikV - No, you're wrong; the challenge is immaterial in this case. Imagine a rugby coach saying, "You're on. This is a hard kick – go make it." In that context, "You're on" has nothing to do with accepting a challenge (rather, it's saying, "It's your turn to go do something"). On the other hand, had the coach said, "This is a hard kick; I don't think you can make it," and the player responded, "You're on," then the two-word phrase would have an entirely different meaning (namely, "I'll accept your challenge, and I'll prove you wrong!").

Comment: @MaulikV, if you review the context around the scene, you'll find that there is no challenge/acceptance involved; the lead-up to this is "get ready because you will need to do X, and you should have 7 or 8 hours to get it", then later "okay, it's time for you to do X *[you're on]* but you only have one hour".

Answer (score 10):

In this context, the meaning of *on* maps to [this definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/on_30):

> **on** (*adverb*) `PERFORMING` performing: *Hurry up with the make-up – I'm on in ten minutes.*

While this meaning is often used in television, radio, and the stage, it could also be used during a con scam (as in the movie), or even in marketing.

At an expo, for example, one of my associates might be getting ready to demo our product, and I might say:

> Okay, you're on. Look sharp; be confident.

Or perhaps my daughter is giving a speech:

> You're on tomorrow. Practice one more time, and then get a good night's rest.